# How to change the exe file size?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have made an browser with python. I converted it into exe file with pyinstaller. But it's size is 109,426kb!!! I need to upload it to some places and it is showing "Please try to upload files under 25md". What will I do? How to change this big exe file 24mb file?

Comment: For starters, I would try another compiler and see if that helps.

Comment: Unless you have included libraries (a lot of them!) that you don't actually use, it's very unlikely this will be possible. Going from 110MB down to 25MB is unlikely to be possible.

Comment: This may mean your browser has too many big dependencies. You need to see what you use and how to reduce it. If you don't do that yet, use virtual environment (or some similar package management tool) to better manage packages for your project only.

Comment: You will need to show your Pyinstaller spec file or other configuration to begin with.

Comment: You may also choose another file sharing service to Upload your file too. Unless you need exactly your current service. There are many services that accept Uploading of files several Gigabytes in size.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try [Nuitka](https://nuitka.net/) instead of PyInstaller.

Unlike PyInstaller, Nuitka usually produces smaller exe binaries. Nuitka compiles all sources to compact machine code and includes strictly only used (recursively imported) modules and not more.

Although it is not guaranteed that Nuitka will make a smaller binary, still you can try it.

To use Nuitka do following steps:

1. Install Nuitka through `python -m pip install nuitka zstandard`. **Important note** - you can see `zstandard` in this command, this module is obligatory to be installed, it is needed to make your final exe binary much smaller, Nuitka automatically uses this module if it is installed.
2. Install C++ compiler, [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.com/) (MSVC) on Windows or GCC on Linux (`sudo apt install g++ gcc`). For Visual Studio it is enought to install Community version. C++ compiler is needed for Nuitka because it converts all python sources to C/C++ and compiles them.
3. If you don't want to install Visual Studio then Nuitka suggests to automatically download/install of MSYS/MinGW toolkit with C/C++ compiler, in build step `5.` described below. During that step it will ask `Proceed with download? [Yes/No]`, type `yes` and Enter. MinGW C++ compiler will be used instead of Visual Studio then. If MinGW will not work for you and print some errors during build then you don't have other choice and you have to install Visual Studio.
4. If on Windows run Visual Studio `Native x64 Command Prompt`, the link to it should be installed and located on your Desktop (or Start menu). On Linux just run terminal. Also change directory to where your python script is located.
5. Run `python -m nuitka --assume-yes-for-downloads --onefile --standalone your_program.py`. Also on some systems prefix `python -m nuitka ...` doesn't work then just use `nuitka` i.e. run `nuitka --assume-yes-for-downloads --onefile --standalone your_program.py`. This will build your final EXE. It takes some time to compile all sources. Also during build Nuitka may ask something like `Package ... is needed for install. Proceed with download? [Yes/No]` several times, type `yes` and press enter to confirm and continue.
6. If there are any warnings or errors during build in step `5.`, please resolve them, this will help you to get very good quality of final EXE. Warnings are shown in red color, one type of warning could be that Nuitka suggests you to install extra module like `zstandard`, do all suggested warnings!
7. If step `5.` is successful you'll get `your_program.exe` file near your python script. This EXE is the only file needed to be Uploaded to your friends, no need for preinstalled Python on theirs machine to run this EXE.

If you're on Windows then you may use two extra flags (if needed) in build step `5.`. First flag is `--windows-uac-uiaccess` - it is needed if your application needs Administrator permissions for some reasons, adding this flag will ask User for granting Admin permission on application's start.

Second Windows flag is `--windows-disable-console` - use it if you don't need console at all when running your application. Use it if you have graphical-only application that doesn't need to show anything in console.

Also run `nuitka --help` to see all available command line options, there many of useful options in Nuitka.

Answer (score 1):

well, I faced the same problem too but in my case, I create a virtual environment and install the module again in the virtual environment the reason for doing this is because when you create an exe file all modules within your pc packed with the exe file (even unnecessary modules), therefore, create a virtual environment it only exports necessary modules then.

https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/ ~ In case you don't know what virtual env is, it's a module that help to separate other modules and only uses the modules installed within the environment